# Add generating headers method to route creating method

Tags: javascript, angular, jwt, authorization

I need an advice how to make my code better.
I have a simple class that gets data from backend that is using jwt token auth.

```
export class RepositoryService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private envUrl: EnvironmentUrlService) { }

  public getData = (route: string) => {
    return this.http.get(this.createCompleteRoute(route, this.envUrl.urlAddress), this.generateHeaders());
  }

 
  private createCompleteRoute = (route: string, envAddress: string) => {
    return `${envAddress}/${route}`;
  }
  private generateHeaders = () => {
    return {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token")}`
        }),
    };
  };
```

It works fine but the problem starts when I get a lot more of http methods. How can I change createCompleteRoute so I won't have to use generateHeaders() in every http method?
I though about doing something like:

```
private createCompleteRoute = (route: string, envAddress: string) => {
    return `${envAddress}/${route}`, this.generateHeaders();
  }
```

so http methods could look like this:

```
public getData = (route: string) => {
    return this.http.get(this.createCompleteRoute(route, this.envUrl.urlAddress));
  }
```

But have no idea how to write a valid function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do what you ask for, could be to bring your logic for creating headers to an **interceptor**, which is going to *automatically add the header parameters to every http call*.

It could be something like this:

Your interceptor file (is kinda service, but have to implement **HttpInterceptor**:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor,
} from '@angular/common/http';

// The service/way you use to get your token
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class MyInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

  intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
  
  const url="\yourAPI\endpoint";
  
    //  Get your token
    cont myToken = this.authService.getToken(); // or localStorage.getItem("token") or whatever your way to get your token
  
    
    // Add authorization header with token if available   
    if (myToken) {
    
       request = request.clone({
          setHeaders: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${currentUser.user.api_token}`,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          url,
        });
        
    } 
    
    ...
    }
```

**EXTRA**: More info about how to adding and updating headers and how to Use the interceptor for Intercepting requests and responses:

[Adding & Updating Headers](http://%20%20https://angular.io/guide/http#adding-and-updating-headers)

[Intercepting request & responses](https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses)